# how to show table, first need get data from file.ts, then need write static data in html, then also from file.ts

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

blue scope need be static html
how to show table, first need get data from file.ts, then need  write  static data in html, then also from file.ts
How need do it do?

```
<table>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let match of matches"> 
    <tr>
       <td *ngFor="let row of match.items">{{row}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

file.ts

```
matches=[
{
 "items": ["Russia ","-",":","-","Saudi Arabia","14/06/18","18:00"]
},
{
 "items": ["Egypt ","-",":","-","Uruguay","15/06/18","15:00"]
},
    {
 "items": ["Russia ","-",":","-","Egypt","06/06/18","21:00"]
    },
    {
 "items": ["Uruguay ","-",":","-","Saudi Arabia","18/06/18","18:00"]
},
         {
 "items": ["Uruguay ","-",":","-","Russia","25/06/18","17:00"]
},          {
 "items": ["Saudi Arabia ","-",":","-","Egypt","25/06/18","17:00"]
}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<table *ngIf="matches.length>0">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let match of matches"> 
    <tr>
       <td *ngFor="let row of match.items">{{row}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: didn't get .. please enplane . its doesnt  work mean not work  at all?